# Executing ELF binaries in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I have a capture the flag (CTF) related question and I was wondering if someone can point me to the right direction.

I work on Mac OS X Yosemite and I was going through some war games and older capture the flag (CTF) challenges. My goal is to execute the ELF binary of the challenge "natively" into my iterm (after I scp it locally) although I realize that only MACH binaries may be executed by the underlying system.

Nevertheless, is such a thing possible through emulation perhaps (e.g. QEMU), or any other method, in order to avoid opening a whole VM just to run a binary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954223/emulating-linux-binaries-under-mac-os-x

Answer (score 5):

The answer is probably: Depends on how the ELF file was generated.

Based on this [article](https://linux-audit.com/elf-binaries-on-linux-understanding-and-analysis), and this sentence:

- A common misconception is that ELF files are just for executables...
- We already have seen they can be used for partial pieces ...

Not all ELF files will be executed, even if you have a proper setup.

Based on this [article](https://icculus.org/fatelf/), there is a group pf ELF files called FatELF:

- FatELF is a file format that embeds multiple ELF binaries for different architectures into one file
- Ship one file that works across Linux and FreeBSD

Based on this [page from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/BSD/BSD.html)

- The BSD portion of the OS X kernel is derived primarily from FreeBSD

So, for Mac OS X, FatELF is the "beginning of the answer".

And finally, based on this [page](http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv):

> Object file converter
>
> This utility can be used for converting object files between COFF/PE, OMF, **ELF** and Mach-O formats for all 32-bit and 64-bit x86 platforms. **Can modify symbol names in object files. Can build, modify and convert function libraries across platforms**. Can dump object files and executable files. Also includes a very good disassembler supporting the SSE4, AVX, AVX2, AVX512, FMA3, FMA4, XOP and Knights Corner instruction sets. Source code included (GPL).

You have a chance to active what you want.

PS: there is another [page about XBinary](http://web.archive.org/web/20200513034604/http://www.osxbook.com/software/xbinary/), I didn't analyze it.

> This document discusses XBinary, a new software that lets you add kernel-level support for executing files in arbitrary binary formats on Mac OS X

Answer (score 2):

On its own, ELF binaries mean nothing. Few binaries run alone - You'd need supporting libraries, APIs and ABIs and other shiny things.

When running QEMU you still need most of the OS - just that its not tied as closely with the host system I suspect.

In theory if you had something like 'wine' but acting as a linux(or other *nix syle OS) -> OS X compatibility layer you *could* get what you want, but such a beast does not exist.

SO no, you can't run an arbitary, precompiled ELF binary on OS X

Comment: this question regards a security scenario that's rather niche in the superuser space.  imagine a static binary (libs compiled into the image rather than dynamically linked) that an attacker wants to place on a target system and run (that's a basic CTF security game scenario).  it won't need external libs, though your point about ABIs (eg syscalls) is a fair one.  you're right in the general case, but this question is specifically not about the general case.  imho it shouldn't have been moved from the security site.